# ZFcuser get information with inner join

Tags: zend-framework2, zfcuser

I have a user table with a store id column (store) that correspondent with a store table.
I'm retrieving this store id with a custom entity object.

Application/Entity/User.php

```
namespace Thuiswinkelen\Entity;

class User extends \ZfcUser\Entity\User
{

/**
 * @var int
 */
protected $store;


public function getStore()
{
    return $this->store;
}

/**
 * Set store.
 *
 * @param int $store
 * @return UserInterface
 */
public function setStore($store)
{
    $this->store = (int) $store;
    return $this;
}


}
```

My question is: How to get the store name in the store table (with an inner join?)
It would be great when I can use something like:

```
<?php echo $this->zfcUserStoreId() ?> 
<?php echo $this->zfcUserStoreName() ?>
```

Comment: Did you checkout for one to many relations in Doctrine ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're looking to map entity relationships; you will need an object relational mapper (ORM), such as Doctrine to accomplish this.

This will convert your foreign identifiers into *objects* in which you can then transverse.

```
$storeName = $user->getStore()->getName();
```

I'm guessing that the examples you have suggested `$this->zfcUserStoreId()` you have invented due to the already existing [`ZfcUser\View\Helper\ZfcUserDisplayName`](https://github.com/ZF-Commons/ZfcUser/blob/master/src/ZfcUser/View/Helper/ZfcUserDisplayName.php)

This however is a [*view helper*](http://zf2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modules/zend.view.helpers.html) and simplify aids the rendering of a user's name based on other configuration.

Comment: I've setup Doctrine and it's working correctly (very useful!). But I do not get it working with getName(); I want to show the store name in the layout. What do I have to do with the $user variabele you showed me?